# Eclipse development - preferencePageId for Eclipse IDE standard preferences pages like "org.eclipse.ui.preferencePages.GeneralTextEditor"

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-plugin

How to discover `preferencePageId` e.g. for General -> Editors -> Text Editors -> Spelling

Details:

Following code can add link to other preferences pages:

```java
    Link link = new Link(parentComposite, SWT.NONE);
    link.setText("Configure general text editors spelling <A>here</A>.");
    FontData[] fontData = link.getFont().getFontData();
    for (FontData fd : fontData) {
        fd.setHeight(10);
        //-fd.setStyle(SWT.BOLD);
    }
    link.setFont(new Font(getShell().getDisplay(), fontData));
    link.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
            IWorkbenchPreferenceContainer container= (IWorkbenchPreferenceContainer) getContainer();
            container.openPage("org.eclipse.ui.preferencePages.GeneralTextEditor", null);
        }
    });
```

However, there is no way I could find list of predefined values like `"org.eclipse.ui.preferencePages.GeneralTextEditor"` for General -> Editors -> Text Editors -> Spelling.

Using [grepcode](http://grepcode.com/search?query=%22org.eclipse.ui.preferencePages.GeneralTextEditor%22) does not find String values.

This is needed for [jdt.spelling](https://github.com/stuarthendren/jdt.spelling/pull/38)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no list anywhere. You can use 'Search > Search... > Plug-in Search' to search the workspace plugin.xml  files for all references to the `org.eclipse.ui.preferencePages` extension point and then look at the results to examine the declarations.

Doing the above I see that the spelling page is defined in the `org.eclipse.ui.editors` plugin and has the id `org.eclipse.ui.editors.preferencePages.Spelling`.

Comment: I wasn't so lucky to find the value. Thank you for sharing that specific one value.

Answer (score 1):

Open a `plugin.xml` that defines any `org.eclipse.ui.preferencePages`, right click on the extension and select `Find References`. The search view will show a list of all declared preference pages. You can then double click on these to open the definition and find the IDs.